# Trying to understand an Inequality in the proof of Hahn Banach

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, hahn-banach-theorem

In our Lecture we had the Hahn Banach theorem:

> Let $X$ be real linear space and $Y$ is its subspace. Also let $p$ be a sublinear functional defined on $X$ and a linear funtional $f$ defined on $Y$ with $f(x) \leq p(x)$ for all $x \in Y$ .
>   Then exists a linear functional $F$ defined on $X$, with $F(x) \leq p(x)$ for all $x \in X$ and $F(x) = f(x)$ for $x\in Y$.

Our proof begins with define $P$ on $X$ with $P(x):=inf(p(x-y)+f(y))$ for $x \in X$.  We have:
$p(x-y)+f(y) \geq p(-y)-p(-x)-f(-y)\geq -p(-x)> - \infty $ .
Especially $P(x)> -\infty$

But i can not see where the first inequality comes from. I think the second one is because of:

$p(-y)-p(-x)-f(-y)\geq -p(-x)$

$p(-y)-f(-y)\geq -p(-x)+p(-x)$

$p(-y)-f(-y)\geq 0$

and this is true because $f(x) \leq p(x)$ for all $x \in Y$ or am I wrong?
Sorry for the bad english. Thanks for any help, I really try to understand the proof!

Comment: The first inequality comes from the subadditivity of $p$. $p(x-y)+p(-x)\geq p((x-y)+(-x))=p(-y)$. Then pass the $p(-x)$ to the right side to get $p(x-y)\geq p(-y)-p(-x)$. Also by subadditivity $p(y)+p(-y)\geq p(y+(-y))=p(0)=0$. So $p(y)\geq -p(-y)$. Adding these two inequalities you get $p(x-y)+p(y)\geq p(-y)-p(-x)-p(-y)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f$ is linear, we have that $f(y)=-f(-y)$. Furthermore,
$p(-y)=p(x-y-x) \leq p(x-y)+p(-x)$, by subadditivity. I think you can use these observations to see why the first inequality is true.